# How to Load Data from .js file to React Component out of .map as individual data

Tags: reactjs, json

I wanted to load few Data from .js file to React Component out of .map as individual data.
From Data.js file  title & Description data need to load after the mapping data  how to call those values?  Please Help

```
export const stockData = [
  {
    title: "Date Loader Demo",
    Description: "Date Loader Demo Description"
  }]

{stockData.title}
{stockData.Description}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/load-data-from-date-file-to-component-le6bpv

Comment: Maybe you should change your data format because it will be undefined first when you map over the array. If you want some sample code then let me know it comment

Comment: please share sample code, thank you.

Comment: Is data fetched from backed? if Yes plz add an API call into your code sandbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw your CodeSandBox project,
In the data.js file you stored stockData as an array and you are calling stockData.title as if .title were a property of an object, that's wrong, you need to explicit the array index of object that contains the properties title and description.

You can simply fix using `[0]`

```js
{stockData[0].title}
{stockData[0].Description}
```

Or using destructuring:

```js
const [firstItem] = stockData
// ...
{firstItem.title}
{firstItem.Description}
```

If you need to wait mapping data be loaded you can use a logical condition, using .length property or another dependency if exists.